# Has Anyone Gotten Selenium 3 (for java) to Work with Firefox Without Any Major Bugs?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium3

I have been Testing **Selenium 3** (with **Firefox**) as soon as it came out and have never been able to get a satisfactory result. So I have been holding off officially moving my team's code to version 3.

However, now one of the apps that we are testing relies on a newer version of Firefox. This is forcing us into Selenium 3, and I have still been unable to get it fully working with all of the functionality that I need.

.

**Here is a list of versions that have tried:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K7DEmO-KRmYw-yJXUQx7dN8dD8CdkuW95AA9C_qKa28/edit?usp=sharing

*(note: this is not the full list, I have only started tracking the versions after it became clear that I was not going to find one that works)*

.

**This is how I am setting up my WebDriver:**

```
System.setProperty( "webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\...\geckodriver" );
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setBinary( "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" );
new FirefoxDriver( firefoxOptions );
```

.

**What am I asking?**
I suppose what I am asking is does anyone have a magic combination of Selenium 3, Gecko Driver, and Firefox; that I have not tried and that does not have any of the issues that I am currently facing?
**OR**, does anyone have a workaround for any of the bugs I am currently facing?

Comment: what kind of problems do you experience?

Comment: They are listed in the Shared Doc...  • Unable to create remote session • setPosition does not work  • CONTROL Key Chords Not Working  • Element Send Keys is broken

Comment: @BrandonDude I am currently working with Selenium 3.4.0 with both Java & Python bindings. I will like to share with you that with the release of Selenium 3.x, Selenium have become more matured. Yes there are certain breakages​ in some of the features but we always have an alternative way out for that. You can raise your issues here one by one. Our community members together we will surely work out a solution for you. Thanks

Comment: *Has Anyone Gotten Selenium 3 (for java) to Work with Firefox Without Any Major Bugs?* more like opinion based.Not everyone is going to use/test all the features/actions of selenium. For me it's ok 98% running without any issue

Comment: @DebanjanB, I cannot speak to Selenium 3 being "more matured". (Having only used it with Firefox gives me limited exposure, and most of the issues that I have found can be attributed to Firefox / Gecko Driver issues.) However, all of the issues that I have encountered are documented bugs (see linked spreadsheet). If there is a way to work around any of those, I would be happy to hear it. :)

Comment: @Madhan I suppose what I am asking for is if anyone has a magic combination of Selenium 3, Gecko Driver, and Firefox; that I have not tried and does not have any of the Issues that I have encountered?

Comment: I finally got it working. See https://github.com/BrandonDudek/swatt for details.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Webdriver from time to time have shown this type of issues, With every new release there will be some issues in browser compatibility. I feel using something like protractor (http://www.protractortest.org/) which wraps selenium webdriver and expose a set of methods to interact with will help to resolve version specific problems like this.

However, one disadvantage is the programming language, Protractor is mainly JavaScript based, and you are using Java. But, Using something like https://github.com/99xt/CodeSpecJS will help you to resolve this issue. With CodeSpecJS you don't write code to define your tests. You use a set of well-defined grammar to define the tests.  I've tried it out in my projects and it seems to work well.

Hope this answer was helpful to you to work with UI Automation in the long run.

Comment: Thanks. But for now, I am tied to Java.